# Need some help on this representation of Traveling Salesman Problem

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, matlab, neural-network, traveling-salesman

I came across a traveling salesman solution which uses Matlab script, and in its code, I found that it uses a representation called City Coordinates, which looks like:

```
CityCood = [0.4000,0.2439,0.1707,0.2239,0.5171;0.4439,0.1463,0.2293,0.7610,0.9414]
```

for 5 cities.

At this point, I am really clueless about how did the author get this representation, since from what I have seen so far, the information at hand should be a 5*5 symmetric matrix representing distance between any two of these five cities.

So I would be grateful if anyone could give me an idea on how that coordinate-based representation works. Thanks in advance.

Comment: consider using camel case for variable names: *cityCoord* instead of *CityCoord*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`CityCoord` (I think there's a letter missing) is a 2-by-5 array. I assume this means that`CityCoord` contains two coordinates (x,y) for every single city.

To create a 5-by-5 distance matrix, you can call

```
squareform(pdist(CityCoord'))
```

Comment: Great. What about if I already have a distance matrix at hand? say, I know the intercity distance for every pair out of 5 cities A,B,C,D,E?

Comment: @Robert: If you need to convert a distance matrix into coordinates, and you have the statistics toolbox, you can use e.g. `mdscale`, as in `CityCoord = mdscale(distanceMatrix,2)';`.

Comment: IPDM for folks without Statistics Toolbox: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/18937

Comment: there's actually an example in the documentation of using CMDSCALE to reconstruct (an approximation) the location of the cities based on their inter-distances: http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/briu08r-1.html#briu08r-4

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have the Statistics Toolbox, an equivalent form to the solution provided by [@Jonas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4306321/need-some-help-on-this-representation-of-traveling-salesman-problem/4306363#4306363) to compute the Euclidean distance is:

```
%# dist(u,v) = norm(u-v) = sqrt(sum((u-v).^2))
D = cell2mat( arrayfun( ...
    @(i) sqrt( sum( bsxfun(@minus, CityCoord, CityCoord(:,i)).^2 ) ), ...
    (1:size(CityCood,2))', ...
    'UniformOutput',false) );
```

Otherwise, we can use the fact that `||u-v||^2 = ||u||^2 + ||v||^2 - 2*u.v` to implement an even faster vectorized code:

```
X = sum(CityCoord.^2);
D = real( sqrt(bsxfun(@plus,X,X')-2*(CityCoord'*CityCoord)) );
```

Comment: +1 for nice and advanced, albeit somewhat difficult to read non-toolbox solutions!

Comment: I tried breaking it down into multiple lines for readability, still one call to PDIST is much easier :)